# C++ operator = overload inherited, is it necessary to redefine in the derived class though defined in the base class?

Tags: c++, inheritance, operator-overloading

Say I have this C++ code:

```
class Base {
public:
 Base& operator=(const Base&);
};

class Derivate : public Base {
public:

};
```

And say I have a main where

```
Derivate d1;
//Something on d1
Derivate d2 = d1;
```

In this situation would the operator `=` of the base class called? I have some code that basically does such thing, but debugging with gdb I don't see any call to such operator.

Is it necessary in this case redifine the operator in the derivate class?

Comment: The compiler is quite happy to implicitly generate one for you. But it's up to you to make sure it has correct semantics.

Comment: So it wouldn't use the inherithed one from the base class, right? Is it the same thing for a copy constructor?

Comment: The reason why your `Base::operator=` isn't being called is that `Derivate d2 = d1;` uses the copy constructor, not the assignment operator.

Comment: It would. The implicitly generated one calls the assignment operator on all base classes and members. The same is true for the copy c'tor. But again, if you have pointers & such in your classes, it will likely not be the behavior you want by default.

Comment: @Brian, why? what's the dynamic that make you state that?

Comment: `type name  = something` is always construction and never assignment.

Answer (score 0):

no in fact you are calling copy constructor because you are assigning d1 to d2 while constructing d2 thus assignment operator is not called here:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Base 
{
    public:
        Base& operator = (const Base&);
};

Base& Base::operator = (const Base&)
{
    cout << "assignment operator" << endl;
    // implementation here
    return *this;
}

class Derivate : public Base
{
    public:
        Derivate(){}
        Derivate(const Derivate& rhs){cout << "copy constructor" << endl;}
};

int main()
{
    Derivate d1;
    //Something on d1
    Derivate d2 = d1; // copy constructor not assignment operstor
    //Derivate d2(d1); // is the same as above calling cpy ctor
    d2 = d1; // here assignment operator is called

    return 0;
}
```

- why `d2 = d1;` calls the base assignment operator?

because if you don't provide a derived class assignment operator the compiler will define one for you as follows:

```
Derivate& operator = (const Base& rhs); // not Derivate
```

so this Derived one calls as you guess the base's assignment operator as long as passing a const reference instead of derived one.

- assignment operator is really inherited:

make it private scoped in base class and see the result.

Comment: The automatically declared assignment operator is `Derivate& operator=(const Derivate&);`, not `Derivate& operator=(const Base&);`.

Comment: @aschepler yes I know I said the compiler adds implicitly `Derivate& operator=(const Base&);` which in turn invokes the base one